# How would a star powered by matter-antimatter annihilation be?

Tags: antimatter, stars

An analogue to our sun or stars but the energy does not come from fusion but from matter antimatter annihilation. If such system could exist, how would it be?

Comment: Well, there is at least one instable answer to your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair-instability_supernova

Comment: This situation is believed to have occurred in the very early universe prior to the hadronization phase.  Matter and anti-matter were created in almost equal amounts and subsequent annihilations left the small excess of matter which is what makes up the universe today (according to commonly accepted theories of cosmology). Things were much hotter and denser than conditions inside a star.

Comment: And they would have annihilated before they could form a star.

Comment: @Stipe thanks, I wasn t aware of that effect. But worthwhile also to note that the pair production is different than annihilation, and in fact it is the creation of particle-antiparticle, that reduces the amount of gamma radiation and thus its pressure in the upper layers and has it collapse faster, but the real supernova explosion is no different, and due to the runaway fusion